# What is the name of a visualization to show inter-dependent events happening in paralel?

Tags: visualization

I'm trying to find an editor to help me draw this type of chart:

[image: Gantt-ish chart]

...but I'm finding it really difficult to do without knowing what to call it.

I want to show a sequence of events that happen over time with connections to each other.

A Gantt chart sort-of fits the bill, but its something a lot more purposeful than what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to plan a project, I'm trying to visualize and their relationships.